# Azure datafactory deployment automation from multiple branches

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I want to create automated deployment pipeline for azure datafactory.
For one stream of development we can configure it using doc 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

But when it comes to deploying to two diff test datafactories for parrallel features development (in two different branches), it is not working because the adb_publish which gets generated is only specific to the one datafactory.

Currently we are doing deployement using powershell scripts and passing object list which needs to be deployed.
Our repo is in Azure devops.

I tried

1. linking the repo to multiple df but then it is causing issue, perhaps when finding deltas to publish.
2. Creating forks of repo instead of branches so that adb_publish can be seperate for the every datafactory - but this approach will not work when there is a conflict, which needs manual merge, so the testing will be required again instead of moving to prod.

Answer (score 2):

Adf_publish get generated whenever you publish. Publishing takes whatever you have in your repo and updates data factory with it.

To develop multiple features in parallel, you need to just use "Save". Save will commit your changes to the branch you are actually working on. Other branches will do the same. Whenever you want to publish, you need to first make a pull request from your branch to master, then publish. Any merge conflict should be solved when merging everything in the master branch. Then just publish and there shouldn't be any conflicts, and adf_publish will get generated after that.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Since a GitHub repository can be associated with only one data factory. And you are only allowed to publish to the Data Factory service from your collaboration branch. [Check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control)

It seems there is not a direct and easy way to accomplish this. If forking repo as workaround, you may have to solve the conflicts before merging as @Martin suggested.